# in emacs, using neotree, how can I yank the full path of the node at point to the kill ring?

Tags: emacs

Suppose I'm using neotree in emacs, and suppose point lies above a node representing a file or a directory.

how can I yank the full path of said node to the kill ring so that I can `C-y` this path afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line` to get the filename or directory at point (which is a STRING), and then using `kill-new` to *make STRING the latest kill in the kill ring*?

The solution, when combined, looks like this:

```
(kill-new (neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line))
```

Comment: hi lawlist, thank you. How should I use your solution? I'm really new in elisp. Do I define an interactive function that uses the neo-buffer function? Will I have access to that private function from my init.el?

Comment: One idea would be to place the following function named `ninrod` inside your `init.el` file, save the file and reboot Emacs:  `(defun ninrod () (interactive) (kill-new (neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line)))`.  You can use `M-x ninrod` to copy your filename or directory at point, and then paste/yank your kill wherever you want.  The method of pasting/yanking remains the same as it has ever been.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file, and then find the location via M-: 'buffer-file-name'. Since you wish to Yank it you can follow some of the approaches listed here:
[File path to clipboard in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416655/file-path-to-clipboard-in-emacs)

Comment: The reason why this answer is less than ideal is because it is not necessary to actually open the file to get the filename or directory at point.  Neotree is a library that generates a tree-view of files and directories.  The filenames and directory names must be known by neotree in order to accurately depict a tree-view of the directories/files.  Neotree is not opening every file that is listed in order to extract the `buffer-file-name`.  Therefore, it is just a matter of examining the code of neotree to see what is already available to extract the filename or directory at point.