# In Dired, how do I add the file path to the kill ring with relevant characters escaped?

Tags: emacs, dired, eshell

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075288/4479455) explains, the Dired function `dired-copy-filename-as-kill` (`0 w`) lets one add the path of the file at point to the kill ring. However, I would like to use this path on Eshell, where characters such as SPC need to be escaped. Is there a way to copy the path to the kill ring with the relevant characters escaped, or to transform a previous kill so as to escape these characters?

Comment: If the filepath contains space, you could use quote to surround it like `cd "a folder with space"`.

Comment: Does `shell-quote-argument` help?

Comment: So far, I've only needed to escape spaces, so enclosing the path in quotes solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `eshell-quote-argument`.

Comment: Thanks, this expands on @Ynjxsjmh's comment above. I see that one can customize the variable ```eshell-special-chars-outside-quoting``` to set the characters that need escaping.

Comment: `(mapcar #'char-to-string eshell-special-chars-outside-quoting)` if you want to see that list in a friendlier format.